# display all the names in team1 and team2

Tags: java, jcreator

Here is the situation. The User will insert names in team1 and team2 via User input then the program will display all the names of TEAM1 and TEAM2. I have a problem in my display methods, because they only display the names in Team1. what i want to do is display all the names in team1 and team2. I am new in programming and i really have a hard time learning. here's my code so far.

```
     class Node
     {
       protected String info;
       protected Node next;
         public Node(String value)
         {
           info = value;
           next = null;
         }
      }

     class LinkedList
     {
        private Node head;
        private int count;

        public LinkedList()
        {
          head = null;
          count = 0;
        }

       public void insertteam1(String name)
       {
           Node b = new Node(name);
           b.next = null;
           count++;
           if (head == null)
           {
            head = b;
            return;
           }
           for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
           {
               if (cur.next == null)
               {
                 cur.next = b;
                 return;
               }

           }
       }

       public void insertteam2(String name)
       {
            Node c = new Node(name);
            c.next = null;
            count++;
            if (head == null)
            {
               head = c;
               return;
            }
            for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
            {
                if (cur.next == null)
                {
                    cur.next = c;
                    return;
                }

            }
         }
         public void displayTeamone()
         {
                for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
                    System.out.print(cur.info + " ");
                System.out.println();
         }
         public void displayTeamtwo()
         {
                for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
                    System.out.println(cur.info + " ");
                System.out.println();
         }
       }
```

Comment: Do you really need to use you own implementation of linked list? Is that homework? If so can you tag it as such?

Comment: Yes it is our homework, the use of arrays is also allowed

Answer (score 0):

You are inserting the two teams into the same list.
Use two head nodes,one for team1 and one for team2.

```
private Node head1;
private Node head2;
```

and reuse the insert function like:

```
public void insertteam(String name,String team)
{
  if(team.equals("team1")
   head = head1;
  else
   head = head2;
   //logic for insert
}
```

Comment: um... we were required to use two methods which is "insertTeamone" and "insertTeamtwo". Can i do it like this instead?                                     public void insertteam1(String name)
{ 
 Node b = new Node(name);
 b.next = null;
 count++;
 if (head1 == null)
 {
  head1 = b;
  return;
 }
 for(Node cur = head; cur != null; cur = cur.next)
 {
  if (cur.next == null)
  {
   cur.next = b;
   return;
  }
  
 }
} i will also replace the head in insertTeamtwo with head2 is that ok?

Comment: Ya you can do that. and its cur = head1 in the for loop initialisation